# JavaScript - Can't access the first element of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to access the first element of the array using the following:

```
array[0];
```

The format of the array

```
var array = [[Object { userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }],[Object { userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }]]
```

However, when trying to do a:

```
  console.log(array[0]);
```

I get `undefined`.

and when running:

```
 console.log(array)
```

[image]

it shows the array contents.

Any ideas on what's  going on?

Comment: It's dimensional array. Logging first item should log the first array.

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(array));` to see what's going on exactly.

Comment: Where does the `var array = [[Object ` syntax come from? It isn't valid JavaScript code and it doesn't seem to be a console.log() dump of any kind :-?

Comment: @electrotype .stringify throws `[]` without JSON.stringify, it throws the same but when I click on it on the console it shows its content

Comment: Agree with @ÁlvaroGonzález, what's that syntax? A real console will throw an error: "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list". That may be a stringified output from the backend?

Comment: @EmrePiskin in the console, it throws `Array [  ]` when doing a `console.log(array);` when I click on `Array [  ]` it shows the objects

Comment: You're most likely printing out the first value of the array before it's populated. For example, this could happen if the array is populated as the result of an asynchronous call, and you're trying to print it out right after the call, before it has any data. Please show us where and how you are setting the array contents.

Comment: @torazaburo what you said may be true, for testing purposes I've removed the code coming from the backend and set the following : `var array = [[{ userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }],[{ userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }]]` however I still have the same result

Comment: Then check out my answer snippet, how is this possible?

Comment: With that other data, [I cannot reproduce it either](http://jsbin.com/zetoqohote/edit?js,console).

Comment: I've updated the post and attached a screenshot of what `console.log(array)` prints out

Comment: Do you get those two different behaviors if you put them in the same place in your code?  Or does `console.log(array)` work  but only at some remove from the original code?

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes at the same place in the code `console.log(array)` differs from `console.log(array[0])` which throws `undefined`

Comment: @FolkyH: Then that is quite mysterious.  Can you add a snippet here or set up a JSFiddle, JSBin or some such with a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: The console log printout you show is the classical case of an array which was empty when logged, then filled in later. The way devtools console works is that when you open up the object/array it will show the **current** contents, but the `[]` at the top remains, showing that it was empty when originally logged. As I said, you must show us the entire code where you are setting the value of this array, and where you are logging it.

Answer (score 1):

They should have been like this syntax from backend:

```js
var array = [
  { userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object },
  { userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }
];

var array2 = [
 [{ userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }],
 [{ userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }]
];

console.log(array);
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: I agree with @Scott, Objects may be console artifacts.

Comment: I've updated the post and attached a screenshot of what `console.log(array)` prints out

Comment: What does `array.forEach(function(e) { console.log(e) });` show?

Comment: it returns `undefined`

Comment: You can also try to see `Object.keys(array)[0];`

Comment: `Object.keys(array)[0];` returns `undefined` too

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "Object" keyword from the beginning of your object.

If it's coming from the backend like that, they aren't sending out valid JSON.

See @EmrePiskin's answer, and I'd assume `currentLocation` should be inflated with an actual object representation as well.

```
var array = [[{ userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }],[{ userId: "FqOANa1w2f", currentLocation: Object }]]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bf7Lanm7/

Comment: It comes from the backend like that, I don't have a control over it

Comment: Not if it's JSON it doesn't.

Comment: Are those `Object` strings just console artifacts?

Comment: @ScottSauyet it would appear so.

Comment: It's the only thing I see that makes sense.  Although, of course, a backend could supply whatever format it chose.

Comment: @Folky.H In the question you don't say anything about any backend. If it comes from an HTTP request you should be able to inspect the exact **string** sent by the server in the *Network* tab. What you've shared appears to be the result of some undisclosed manipulation.

Comment: `Object ` strings are console artifacts

Comment: I've updated the post and attached a screenshot of what `console.log(array)` prints out